# Deleted Ubuntu partition Windows 10

Tags: grub2, windows-10, partitioning, grubrescue, boot-partition

I was running out of space for Windows 10, so I deleted my Ubuntu partition and then combined the free space and added it to the Windows 10 partition into a single partition (the boot partition was untouched). Now all I get when I turn on my computer is:

```
Error no such partition.
>grub rescue
```

I have tried rebooting, but it did not work.
Is there any way to fix it?
My idea is that if i reinstalled Ubuntu it may fix it, but I'm not sure. I don't have a Windows repair disk, and I can't make one, but I do have a 4GB USB flash drive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84227/discussion-on-question-by-wahgeek-deleted-ubuntu-partition-windows-10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log on with Live Session of your Current Ubuntu Version.
Open Disks app
and mount the EFI partition.
you will see the partition being mounted and a icon on Desktop.
Open it and find EFI folder, from that delete the Ubuntu folder.
Power off the system.
Resrat, you should see windows.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: i will try that but isnt the grub boot in my mbr partition

Comment: If it's UEFI installation, you will see EFI partition. Other wise, mount the first few partitions and look for "ubuntu " folder same as in EFI folder. Since you deleted root partition of Ubuntu.. You will find ubuntu folder in first few partitions as of now. I did it several times. Have you extended the free space to C drive of windows or other partition?

Comment: i extended the free space to windows (c:)

Comment: Ok first you try to delete ubuntu entry and see. I have installed Ubuntu first and windows next so the Ubuntu's space gone to start of windows c drive and it did not boot.. I had repair with windows installation media in such case. Anyway you first try.

Comment: is there a way to set the windows boot loader as my boot insted of grub

Comment: In resent days for UEFI mother boards there are options but in your case.. No as per the options you mentioned from your BIOS setup. But can you please try to delete ubuntu entry first? I am 100% sure if you didn't extended the free space to C Drive.

Comment: If you had deleted Ubuntu root partition and extended the space to C drive within Windows... Then no problem.

Comment: yeah it was extended to c

Comment: if i cant fix this then i may reinstall windows completely

Comment: I mean you deleted and extended when you are on windows login or Ubuntu login? No need reinstallation of windows.. You just need windows bootable media if it's not successful from Ubuntu live session which is very rare.

Comment: so what do i do theres the grub rescue and there are TWO partitions The windows 10 partition and the MBR partition and i dont valuble data on my harddrive so mabey a reinstalltion will fix this

Comment: but i want to try to fix the boot partition cause i dont want ubuntu and grub just windows boot loader and windows 10

Comment: You already deleted Ubuntu root partition. Now only thing left on your system are windows boot manager, windows10 and data along with this small "ubuntu" folder which is grub. Once you delete this "ubuntu" folder nothing remains in your system that relates to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Worked For me

The pendrive in which grub(~2.8mb)(NOT GRUB rescue it is already running if anything else is not damaged) is installed is what you need.

Press F9 ' boot device select'
(bootloader is grub , not the stock bootloader that came with windows)

Select the pendrive in which grub is but not uefi in bracket one

Go to boot manually and select windows , the first option it will boot windows without any problem.

After 2 days wasting in going to shops i found out answer was in front of me.

But i have still not yet removed grub.
Going to install SSD for these kinds of experiments later on.