# Laptop booting to GRUB shell

Tags: grub2, boot-repair, grubrescue, grub-efi

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop, dual booting with Windows, with GRUB as the boot manager.

Earlier today, I booted into Windows and shrunk the Windows partition. After attempting to reboot into Ubuntu, I got a GRUB shell saying `Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.` followed by `grub>`. In an attempt to fix this, I booted with my Ubuntu live USB to install and run boot-repair. When I did this, boot-repair got stuck in a loop saying `filesystem repair requires to unmount partitions`. Generating a BootInfo file gave me [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nprmshhyyP/).

`/dev/sda` is referring to the live USB stick I am using. `/dev/nvme0n1` refers to my SSD, where Windows and Ubuntu are installed. Opening GParted shows an exclamation mark next to `/dev/nvme0n1p7` (dumpe2fs: Invalid argument while reading journal inode), as well as `/dev/nvme0n1p8` and `/dev/nvme0n1p9` (similar errors for both):

```
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/nvme0n1p8 is missing
```

These two partitions used to be detected as the Ubuntu primary partition and the swap partition, respectively. If I run `fdisk -l`, it actually lists them both with a type of `Linux filesystem`.

What is likely to have gone wrong, and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: In such case I would make windows to boot by this https://askubuntu.com/a/1082033/739431 and then reinstall grub by this https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/739431

Comment: If damaged, you may need fsck, but only on the ext4 partition. Swap has no file structure but should be seen as swap. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789