# Ubuntu Boot Option Still In Boot Menu

Tags: boot, uninstall, boot-partition

I deleted my Ubuntu partition, but it still shows up in the boot menu, when I did bcdedit it doesn't show up just a Windows Boot Manager and Windows Boot Loader.

Could one of those accidentally somehow be Ubuntu? [image]

[image]

PS. I was at a friends and he said he fixed it by getting that grub gru pop up removed when i start my windows which he did, but when i got home it was still in my boot menu

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1082033/739431 check this Q&A and comments

Comment: You need to both remove /EFI/ubuntu folder in ESP and ubuntu entries in UEFI NVRAM. https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi Also similar to this, but is delete Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the details right off hand, but if you're using the Windows boot manager, I "think" its options are stored in C:\boot.ini .  It is a hidden/system file, so you'll have to check some boxes to be able to see and edit it, but you can add or remove boot options there.

Just be very careful because messing up this file can brick your boot process.  It might be a good idea to make a backup copy that you can restore with a Linux LiveCD, "just in case".