# I deleted Ubuntu partition, from dual boot. And I'm cut off from Windows!

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Well, I did a really stupid thing...

I deleted the Ubuntu partition, from a dual boot laptop.
Now, whenever I start the computer, I see:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. 
For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. 
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions".
```

And I can't get out of here... from this bash.

The problem is that any of the suggestions on this forum assume that I have access to Windows, which I don't... but I am able to enter the bios.

I'm getting a bit desperate here...

I've tried exit in the bash, but I get sent to the same bash, after what seems to be a restart.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082021/deleted-ubuntu-partition-windows-10). This only works if both Ubuntu and Windows were installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: No *supported* Ubuntu release on this site uses that version of `grub2` as it's very old. Boot windows media & correct the issue there (*windows has commands to make it own the boot process; the command varies on version - but this should ideally be done before you deleted your old/unwanted/unsupported OSes*)

Comment: After pressing F12 (with a bootable USB), I managed to get access to Windows. Then I followed these instructions to remove grub. https://www.binaryera.com/2020/08/RemoveGrubFromWindow10.html

Comment: By the way, whoever put up that link which supposedly already has some answers, they should also now that many of those answers are really old, and outdated.